# Can I programmatically check the status of a paragraph in Zeppelin?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, apache-zeppelin

I'm using Zeppelin with Hadoop on a Spark cluster.

I'd like to check the status of a paragraph, to see whether it's `SUCCESS, RUNNING, NOT RUN OR ERROR.`

I know that I can scroll to the paragraph and read the work in the top right.

Can I check the state of a paragraph programmatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can. Zeppelin exposes a [REST API](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.8.1/usage/rest_api/notebook.html#get-the-status-of-a-single-paragraph) that you can use to manage it.

As it says in the documentation, you can send a GET request to:

> http://[zeppelin-server]:[zeppelin-port]/api/notebook/job/[noteId]/[paragraphId]

and if successful will return a JSON response:

```
{
  "status": "OK",
  "body": {
      "id":"20151121-212654_766735423",
      "status":"FINISHED",
      "finished":"Tue Nov 24 14:21:40 KST 2015",
      "started":"Tue Nov 24 14:21:39 KST 2015"
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I do that inline within a Zeppelin document?

Comment: I have a working instance of Zeppelin under my control. I have a working notebook at http://host:PORT/notebook/#/notebook/someGUID. I get Error 404 when I try `curl -XGET http://host:PORT/api/interpreter`. I am new to Zeppelin. What am I missing? Do I need to use the same PORT, or configure a separate one?