# Is there any way to run a separate notebook after one process is finished in zeppelin?

Tags: pyspark, apache-zeppelin

Suppose the following is the example process

```
Notebook1

df.count()
df.show()
```

```
Notebook2

df2.count()
df2.show()
```

I want to call Notebook2 on zeppelin after Notebook1 is finished.

Answer (score 0):

you need to access to dispatching system(eg: azakaban), zeppelin does not provied the note dependency

Answer (score 0):

there are two ways

1. at the end of last paragraph of notebook1, you can call
   z.run("", "paragraphid of notebook2");
2. there is a rest call( https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.8.1/usage/rest_api/notebook.html#get-the-status-of-a-single-paragraph ) in zeppelin by which you can check the status of paragraphs, such as running state or finished. as soon as you get the status as finished of notebook1's last paragraph then you can call the notebook2's paragraph.

for more reference: [Can I programmatically check the status of a paragraph in Zeppelin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61926936/can-i-programmatically-check-the-status-of-a-paragraph-in-zeppelin)